# How to access movieclip using string?

Tags: string, actionscript-3, movieclip

I tried to access the movieclip using its name but failed.

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.

```
var i = 5;
var me:Array = new Array("num1-xd", "num2-xd2","num3-xd3");
var cool:Array;
var sq:Square;
for each(var wew:Object in me)
{
    //trace(me);
    cool = wew.split("-");
    sq = new Square();
    sq.x = 3;
    sq.y = sq.height + i;
    i += sq.height + 4;
    sq.name = String(cool[1]);
    sq.instanceName = String(cool[1]);
    addChild(sq);
    sq.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace(e.target.name);
    });
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, KeyisDown);
function KeyisDown(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var me2:String = "xd";
    var me3:DisplayObject = stage.getChildByName(me2);
    me3.x += 5;
}
```

I can't access `xd` movieclip on the stage and make it move.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just have the movieclips on the main timeline you could try this["xd"].x += 5; or this[me2].x += 5;

Comment: thanks, it works after I removed "stage.getChildByName(me2);
it should be getChildByName(me2);

Answer (score 0):

If you declared the variables on stage

Use:

`this.xd`

`this.xd.x += 5;`